# Having trouble training Word2Vec iteratively on Gensim

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

I'm attempting to train multiple texts supplied by myself iteratively. However, I keep running into  an issue when I train the model more than once:

> ValueError: You must specify either total_examples or total_words, for proper learning-rate and progress calculations. If you've just built the vocabulary using the same corpus, using the count cached in the model is sufficient: total_examples=model.corpus_count.

I'm currently initiating my model like this:

```py
model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=0, workers=cpu_count())
model.build_vocab(sentences, update=False)
model.save('firstmodel.model')

model = Word2Vec.load('firstmodel.model')
```

and subsequently training it iteratively like this:

```py
model.build_vocab(sentences, update = True)
model.train(sentences, totalexamples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)
```

What am I missing here?

Somehow, it worked when I just trained one other model, so not sure why it doesn't work beyond two models...

Answer (score 0):

First, the error message says you need to supply either the `total_examples` or `total_words` parameter to `train()` (so that it has an accurate estimate of the total training-corpus size).

Your code, as currently shown, only supplies `totalexamples` – a parameter name missing the necessary `_`. Correcting this typo should remedy the immediate error.

However, some other comments on your usage:

- repeatedly calling `train()` with *different* data is an expert technique highly subject to error or other problems. It's not the usual way of using `Word2Vec`, nor the way most published results were reached. You can't count on it to always improve the model with new words; it might make the model worse, as new training sessions update some-but-not-all words, and alter the (usual) property that the vocabulary has one consistent set of word-frequencies from one single corpus. The best course is to `train()` once, with *all* available data, so that the full vocabulary, word-frequencies, & equally-trained word-vectors are achieved in a single consistent session.

- `min_count=0` is almost always a bad idea with word2vec: words with few examples in the corpus should be *discarded*. Trying to learn word-vectors for them not only gets weak vectors for those words, but dilutes/distracts the model from achieving better vectors for surrounding more-common words.
- a count of `workers` up to your local `cpu_count()` only reliably helps up to about 4-12 workers, depending on other parameters & the efficiency of your corpus-reading, then more `workers` can *hurt*, due to inefficiencies in the Python GIL & Gensim corpus-to-worker handoffs. (inding the actual best count for your setup is, unfortunately, still just a matter of trial and error. But if you've got 16 (or more) cores, your setting is almost sure to do worse than a lower `workers` number.

Comment: Thank you so much — the error was fixed and it's working now. On your note about not iteratively training Word2Vec — I'm currently looking at around tens of thousands of Wikipedia pages that are all part of the corpus, and I'm wondering what you would suggest to be the best way to train all of them? Should I combine into a doc and train? Should I use Doc2Vec? I'm a novice and this is for my NLP class, so I would really appreciate some general direction.

Comment: A single call to the `.train()` method can pass in a corpus of any size, with any number of texts, even if the corpus is larger than the system's memory, by using a Python re-iterable sequence. That is, something that satisfies the Python 'iterable' contract: it can be iterated over multiple times, and each iteration returns one item at a time. `Word2Vec` specifically needs each item to be a Python `list` of individual string words.

Comment: If you can get your data into a plain-text file, with one multi-word text per line, and words separated by spaces, there's a helper class in Gensim called `LineSentence` that you can initialize with the path to the file, then will work as a `Word2Vec` corpus that can return all the texts in repeated iterations. The Gensim docs & tutorials include examples of its use.

Comment: You'd only want to use `Doc2Vec` if you were trying to create doc-vectors instead of (or in addition to) word-vectors – but it works roughly the same way, except each item from the iterable needs to be a `TaggedDocument` object that gives not just the list-of-words but also `tags` to specify how the doc-vectors should be named.